# Label a random variable using an i.i.d

Tags: group-theory, probability-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I'm reading the paper [Kesten’s theorem for Invariant Random Subgroups](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3399.pdf)
and am trying to understand what exactly is meant by labeling the vertices of the random variable $G$ using a uniform i.i.d. - in what way does this serve to create the measure $\mu$, which is supposed to end up being $\Gamma$-invariant. Also, I'm not very clear on how $X$ ends up being a Borel-space. What is the product topology referring to here (the Schreier graphs have the Chabauty topology, but what about the label functions?)

This comes from:

[image]

Comment: Here are a few thoughts: 

1) Note that the action of $\Gamma$ essentially ends up permuting the vertices (it changes your root coset from $H$ to $gH$), so when the labels are chosen iid, each graph with labels has "equal probability" (continuous, but the same idea). 

2) number of vertices is countable, so the intended topology on $f$ is most likely the one generated by finite dimensional sets (see Kolmogorov's extension theorem to see how you can generate it)